# NFC Readers + Raspberry Pi + iOS

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, nfc, pcsc

I would like to place 4-6 NFC readers in a car, one for each seat. Passengers who come in will have an id tag with an NFC tag.

I need a way to connect all the usb nfc readers to one raspberry pi device and then have the raspberry pi send the data to an iOS device via a wired connections. Once the iOS device receives the data, it will make a network request.

Questions:

1. What wire could send data from a raspberry pi to an iOS device so we don’t have to rely on Bluetooth.
2. Is there an ideal OS I should use for the raspberry pi?
3. How can I ensure I can get up to 6 usb connections to one device?

Thank you

Comment: You probably can't get a wired connection to an ios app; Hardware that connects to the Lightning port needs to be MFi certified.  BLE would be much simpler.  You could get a lightning to Ethernet adapter and use an Ethernet cable to connect the Raspberry Pi to the ios device

Comment: Why do you need exactly wired connection? What's wrong with bluetooth or wifi, which is in the latest models?

Comment: @vasily , looking for something that would connect automatically and not have to worry about any Bluetooth pairing

Comment: Then for first quest only one path. As @Paulw11 said use MFi. https://mfi.apple.com/en/how-it-works.html But I think connection will not be so simple as you like. You may open WiFi connection via WPS or via QR for more simple connection.
As for other questions, I think you should start from Debian. And USB devices you may connect via usb hubs or usb via ethernet. As you like ;)

Comment: Be aware that signing an MFi license with Apple is a major undertaking; You need to be a company and you will need an MFi manufacturing partner to work with.  You are going to have to set up the app anyway.  Once you tell the app which BLE peripheral to connect to it should be automatic moving forward.  If it is just for your own use, you might be able to use this https://redpark.com/serial-power-adapter-l4-serp-2/